# install4j extra dock icon on OSX for elevated privilege

Tags: java, macos, install4j

When running the installer, an extra java icon appears on the dock next to our installer icon. It appears right after the root privilege request. 
Its title is com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication

I guess this is a helper process that handles all the privileged actions. But I don't want end users to see this separate icon. How do I hide it? Is there any way to add a parameter like "-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true" to this helper thing?

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What version of install4j and what version of Mac OS X do you use? Do you also get this behavior with the "samples/hello/hello.install4j" project?

Comment: Sample project doesn't do this.One difference is that my project includes a json library jar in the installer's custom code.Do you know if that is the reason?

Comment: I added the same library jar to hello project and it still worked fine without showing extra icon. Any advice on how to debug this?

Comment: Please send your .install4j project file to support@ej-technologies.com

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause myself. I specifies non-default colors in Installer->Configuration->GUI Options-> title bar. They doesn't seem to do anything on osx expect bringing up the extra icon. Setting them to default fixes the issue.